# puppeteer request.continue can not work with header host overrided

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

**Tell us about your environment:**

- Puppeteer version: 1.19.0
- Platform / OS version: Debian 9
- URLs (if applicable):
- Node.js version: 8

**What is the expected result?**

I want override the request's host in header.
Such as a request url: `http://a.com/x.jpg`. The DNS resolver may be parse the host to a slower ip address, but I know ther is a better ip like  `1.2.3.4`. I want to change the url with the ip addrees and modify the host in request header.

like from `curl http://a.com/x.jpg`

to `curl --header "Host:a.com" http://1.2.3.4/x.jpg`

**What happens instead?**

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {
  const newHeaders = Object.assign({}, request.headers(), {
    Host: 'a.com'
});

request.continue({ headers: newHeaders, url: 'http://1.2.3.4/x.jpg' });
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you should use request.respond to overwrite headers as below:

```js
 page.on('request', request => {
  request.respond({
        headers:{...request._headers,your_new_header_key:value},
        body
  })
});
```