# Puppeteer Connect through IP

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a problem with connecting through IP to certain website. I install Google Chrome using Docker and then connect to the current instance using `puppeteer.connect()`:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const IP = '104.20.0.109'

    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
      browserURL: 'http://localhost:9222' //connect to Google Chrome
    })

    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ host: 'www.skillshare.com'}) //configure host to connect via IP
    await page.setUserAgent('MyUserAgent')

    await page.goto(`http://${IP}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })

    console.log('Yeah, it works!')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Are you kidding me?')
  }
})()
```

Also I tried setting the `host` header as follows:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true)

page.on('request', request => {
  const headers = request.headers()

  headers['host'] = 'www.skillshare.com'

  request.continue({ headers })
})
```

**Headers:**

```
{
  host: 'www.skillshare.com',
  'user-agent': '<looooong string>'
}
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup google-chrome \
  --no-sandbox \
  --disable-background-networking \
  --disable-default-apps \
  --disable-dev-shm-usage \
  --disable-extensions \
  --disable-gpu \
  --disable-setuid-sandbox \
  --disable-sync \
  --disable-translate \
  --headless \
  --hide-scrollbars \
  --lang=en_US \
  --metrics-recording-only \
  --mute-audio \
  --no-first-run \
  --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update \
  --ignore-certificate-errors \
  --ignore-ssl-errors \
  --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list \
  --user-data-dir=/tmp \
  --remote-debugging-port=9222 \
  --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0
```

**Note:**

I tested with `puppeteer.launch()` and it worked, but I need it to work using `puppeteer.connect()`. I can also easily connect by domain, but IP does not work.

**Error:**

```
Error: net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT at http://104.20.0.109
    at navigate (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:120:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:94:17)
    at async Frame.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:406:12)
    at async Page.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:672:12)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:672:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
    at c.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle.min.js:1:3204)
    at /app/build/bundle.min.js:1:1256
    at Object.next (/app/build/bundle.min.js:1:1361)
    at n (/app/build/bundle.min.js:1:107)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

**Related Questions:**

- [puppeteer request.continue can not work with header host overrided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60539833/9464680)

**Update:**

As I understand it, there is no way to set `Host`, so maybe this question has no answer.

Comment: are you exposing the right ports thru docker?

Comment: @DanielA.White, sure

Comment: How are you launching chrome? I think you need `--remote-debugging-port 9222`.

Comment: @D.Pardal, I already have this flag

Comment: fyi you can launch chrome in code with chrome-launcher, there's a nice example [here](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/getting-to-know-puppeteer-using-practical-examples/#connecting-chromium) with options and websocket connection

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It is better to connect to the chrome instance then launch it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to launch your chrome instance with `--remote-debugging-port=9222` to let `puppeteer.connect()` connect to the browser.

*Edit:* I see you are already using this flag.

If it wouldn't solve your problem: consider connecting via [websocket endpoint](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.1&show=api-browserwsendpoint) instead of `browserURL`.

Comment: I just tried connecting via websocket endpoint and still doesn't work :|

Comment: What is the exact error msg it throws, or if there is no error then: any notable visual signs of not working?

Comment: What if you remove the line temporarily `await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ host: 'www.skillshare.com'}) `? There are reported errors with `host` header set via `setExtraHTTPHeaders` https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5077#issuecomment-588326506

Comment: When connecting via IP I must use the Host header otherwise it doesn't connect  :/